# Beginners Java (Loops) - Vending machine

Tags: java, if-statement, command-line, while-loop, infinite-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cat{

    public static void main(String args[]){

       System.out.print("Enter a command = ");

       double balance = 0;
       String a;

       //scanner input
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       String command = in.nextLine();

       while (in.hasNext()){

            if (command.equals("penny")){
                balance = balance + 0.01;   
                System.out.println("balance = " + balance); 
            }

            if (command.equals("nickel")){
                balance = balance + 0.05;
                System.out.println("balance = " + balance); 
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("return" + balance + "to customer"); 
                break;
            }

            balance++; 
       }

    }

}
```

I'm trying to create an infinite loop that keeps reading new commands for a vending machine , that may halt only under certain condition - when the input is `"return"`, it prints the current balance in the string `"return $XX to customer"`. (otherwise it keeps adding/subtracting cash to the current balance).

First, I cannot seem to get the if and else part integrated together since both the string commands (`"return ~ to customer "& "balance ="`) appears when I write `'penny'`. 
Second problem is that my intended infinite command loops just becomes a flow of infinite numbers in my terminal and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: Please indent your code before posting it. Right now, it's very hard to read.

Comment: What are the infinite numbers?

Comment: The numbers are just rapidly increasing to thousands and more.

Answer (score 1):

Don'y know if it's what you're searching to do, but this loops unitil you send the `break` command:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cat {

 public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.print("Enter a command = ");

    double balance = 0;
    String a;
    // scanner input
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (in.hasNext()) {
                    String command = in.nextLine();
        if (command.equals("penny")) {
            balance = balance + 0.01;
            System.out.println("balance = " + balance);
        } else if (command.equals("nickel")) {
            balance = balance + 0.05;
            System.out.println("balance = " + balance);
        } else if (command.equals("break")) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("return " + balance + " to customer");
        }

        balance++;
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: The problem of the solution posted in the question was basicly related to the problem that command was not updated. That is fixed in this answer.

Comment: I have gotten rid of the balance ++ and it works perfectly as I intended!! Thank you so much for helping I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your broken 'if' add yet another else:

```
 else if (command.equals("nickel")){
```

With java7 you can use switch:

```
switch(command) {
    case "nickel":
        ....
        break;
    case "penny":
        .....
        break;
    default:
       .....; 
}
```